# How to install the optimization pack pyOpt in Python on windows

Tags: python, windows, optimization, installation

I have Anaconda pack for Python installed on my windows 7 laptop.

I followed all the installation steps as explained at:
http://www.pyopt.org/install.html#installation

After some trial and error, I could install pyOpt using the following command:

```
python setup.py install --compiler=mingw32
```

But still, I can't run even the simplest tutorial example at ..
http://www.pyopt.org/tutorial.html

.. maybe because the optimizer SLSQP is missing in the installation. I get following error message when I run the tutorial example:

```
slsqp = pyOpt.SLSQP()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SLSQP'
```

How can I install pyOpt completely with optimizers etc. on windows?

Comment: Hi,
how did you fix this problem finally? I am getting the same error on a windows installation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to preface this with: I know very little about what I am doing...

I've been stuck on this for a long time too. I have a feeling it has something to do with how the modules are built during installation. I think the pyOpt modules all point to fortran and c libraries which are "translated" to python when you run

```
python setup.py install --compiler=mingw32
```

I have been playing around using different compilers and command environments (administrator privledges, powershell, cygwin, etc.) to no avail. The msvc compiler fails at a certain point. Cygwin, MinGW32, IntelEM, all compile but produce the same error when going to run the actual examples.

If you look in the C:\PathToPython\Lib\site-packages\pyOpt\ folder you'll see the folders with all the modules. When you call import, you're importing these modules... so by entering the following (for example... I think):

```
from pyOpt import pySNOPT
```

you are more or less instructing the imports to navigate through the folders to find pySNOPT and import it ... I think. You'll notice that in \pyOpt\pySNOPT\ there is a file pySNOPT.py. When importing, using *from pyOpt import SNOPT* it looks in pyOpt for SNOPT.py... but you'll find (as python has) that there is NO such file to import. Instead, there is only a pySNOPT.py. Knowing this we would expect the following to fix the problem:

```
from pyOpt.pySNOPT import pySNOPT
```

But this, too, fails. This time producing an import error stating "SNOPT shared library failed to import" (this is a pretty big clue, I suspect).

If you open the pySNOPT.py (this could be replaced with the acronyms for any of the other solvers) file you'll see the familiar format of a python module staring back at you. The first lines of all of these files goes something like:

```
try:
    import snopt
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('SNOPT shared library failed to import')
```

This is where the breakdown occurs. The "import snopt" line is supposed to load the snopt.dll (snopt.so, snopt.a for Linux, Unix). When running setup.py, if I use a cygwin environment it creates DLLs in each of the C:\PathToCygwinDrive\lib\python2.7\site-packages\pyOpt\pyACRONYM folders. These DLLs do NOT appear to be placed in the location corresponding to the version of Python I am telling PyCharm to use (c:\PathToPython\Lib\site-packages\pyOpt\pyACRONYM). I used all of the compilers (including cygwin) in other environments (powershell, Visual C++ 2008 64-bit command prompt, any other command prompt for that matter). Simply copying and pasting the DLLs from the Cygwin pyOpt folder to the regular Python pyOpt folder did not work. I don't know if there's a special way that DLLs have to be imported or something. Reading up on building C extensions and linking them to python projects got over my head and tedious way too fast.

I thought this was local to my computer (since a group member managed to get his installation working) but when going through setup on another group member's computer I ran into the EXACT same error.

One important thing to note... I am doing everything in x64 architecture (as was the group member who I tried to help but also got stuck here). This might be the real secret to fixing this. Perhaps there are too many hoops to jump through to get pyOpt working on 64-bit Python. Which brings me to my last point... there some workarounds I can think of:

1. install 32-bit Python, restart the process.
2. install Spyder IDE (through anaconda or something), then install pyOpt using:

   ```
   conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/melund pyopt
   ```

   or

   ```
   conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/mutirri pyopt
   ```

   (both for x64 windows)
   DO NOT use the default conda pyOpt (conda install pyopt) as this is version 0.84 and will not work.
3. Switch to Linux (since programming with linux is like using lube with anal... you CAN make it work without it... but everything will be a lot more painful)

These are the workarounds I've found so far. I hope someone posts an actual solution SOON!

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to install pyOpt on Win64 on Anaconda. Here is how:

One can use the command from the comment above to install pyOpt 1.2 from `mutirri` channel:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/mutirri pyopt
```

Installation goes almost smoothly. With the only exception that it asks to install Microsoft MPI package in order for pyOpt to work properly (that is easy: just go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49926 and download the latest installer).

However, when we try to run some test script for pyOpt, an attempt to use the SLSQP solver fails. Surprise! So, some research is needed.

If we load `Lib\site-packages\pyOpt\pySLSQP\slsqp.pyd` file into Dependency Walker we can see that `LIBGFORTRAN-3.DLL` file is missing.

Quik google search shows that `LIBGFORTRAN-3.DLL` file comes bundled with MinGW64. So, we need to download and install MinGW64 using installer from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/

Then locate `LIBGFORTRAN-3.DLL` in the `mingw64\bin` folder and copy **all** DLLs from this folder somewhere into the PATH (I just copied all mingw64 DLLs to `C:\Anaconda2\Library\bin`).

Now SLSQP solver works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using pyOpt on Windows, I couldn't use any pyOpt library that were written in fortran. The above solutions didn't work for me so I add my own answer here, I hope it helps:

Install these libraries:

```
conda install libpython
conda install -c msys2 m2w64-toolchain
```

Check if fortran compiler are available:

```
f2py -c --help-fcompiler
```

You can install one:

```
conda install -c conda-forge fortran-compiler
```

Delete or uninstall any prior version of pyOpt

Download pyOpt-master from https://github.com/madebr/pyOpt

Go in the appropriate folder and try to run the following line in anaconda prompt:

```
python setup.py install --compiler=mingw32
```

If the option --compiler is not recognized, try to run the following lines:

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
python setup.py install
```

If it doesn't work try the following:

Go in the following directory (or equivalent):C:\Users...\Anaconda3\Lib\distutils

Open or create file distutils.cfg

(You can do it with the following line if you have notepad, it will create and open the file):

```
notepad distutils.cfg
```

In distutils.cfg add these two lines:

```
[build]           
compiler=mingw32.exe
```

Then go back in the pyOpt master directory and run this line in anaconda prompt:

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

If it worked:

In distutils.cfg, remove '.exe', so you have these two lines:

```
[build]           
compiler=mingw32
```

And run this line:

```
python setup.py install
```

If everything went well pyOpt should have appeared where you wanted (in my case, C:\Users...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages).
You can try to run python examples\parallel_gradient.py or any other exemple to see if it worked.

I think it should do but other things I have done before might be necessary:

If this doesn't work, try that:

If you have installed mingGW with conda, uninstall it, I think you can do it with:

```
conda uninstall -c anaconda MinGW
```

Download the latest version of mingw-w64: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds

In Anaconda3\DLLs you may put:

libatomic-1.dll

libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

libgfortran-3.dll

libcomp-1.dll

libquadmath-0.dll

libssp-0.dll

libstdc++-6.dll

libwinpthread-1.dll

One was already there, libfortran-3.dll was downloaded from internet, the rest are copies from minGW-w64

(I found them in C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin)

The path depends on where you installed minGW-w64 and may depend on your version. Copy ALL the DLL somewhere the sys.path have access to(Anaconda3\DLLs for me).

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in Windows using 64-bit Python 3:

- unzip swigwin and add to environment variables
- unzip wingw-w64 and add to environment variables, place at very beginning

Run the following command from the pyOpt folder:

```
python setup.py install --compiler=mingw32
```

If you have tried to compile it, you may need to delete the build folder first

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your answer seems to cover the basics however it seems to miss some details i.e. "add to environment variables", "place at very beginning" is a bit unclear, and it would be useful to have links and more details about the steps you took to make your answer really stand out. This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Thanks again for your contribution, and good luck!