# pyOpt for python 3 install error

Tags: python, windows, optimization, installation

I find a pyOpt package compatible for python3:
https://github.com/madebr/pyOpt

I install it using a command window like bellow:
    `python setup.py install`
there's are some warnings or errors in the installation process:

1. `cobylamodule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pyflush_` and some nearly the same instruction like this
2. `File "C:\Users\tsing\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyOpt\pySNOPT\pySNOPT.py", line 422
   if mode <> 0 and self.h_start:
            ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

though it looks like the install is nearly a success, after that I tried to run some problem but faced the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

`File "C:/Users/tsing/OneDrive/Python Code/pyOpt-for3/pyOpt-master/examples/tp037_resetbyTsing.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyOpt.pySLSQP import SLSQP
ImportError: cannot import name 'SLSQP'`

there are only 2 optimizer writen in python can run, but when I look up the optimizer file in the anaconda lib like:`C:\Users\tsing\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyOpt\pySLSQP` I find that there's a 'source' file missing compared with the original file unziped from the download pyOpt,and that file contains the real solver like pySLSQP

My operation system is X64 WIN10

I just don't know what's wrong with this, could someone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

For sure installing pyopt is not easy. Following the suggestion of Tom Gresavage ([How to install the optimization pack pyOpt in Python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956706/how-to-install-the-optimization-pack-pyopt-in-python-on-windows)), I've installed it with

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/mutirri pyopt
```

Now, the funny part: using this code as a test (say ex1.py)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyOpt import *
from pyOpt.pySDPEN.pySDPEN import SDPEN

def objfunc(x):
    """Solves Rosenbrock's Unconstrained Problem.

        min     100*(x2-x1^2)**2 + (1-x1)^2
        s.t.:   -10 <= xi <= 10,  i = 1,2

        f* = 0 , x* = [1, 1]
    """
    f = 100 * (x[1] - x[0]**2)**2 + (1 - x[0])**2
    g = []
    fail = 0
    return f, g, fail


opt_prob = Optimization('Rosenbrock Unconstraint Problem', objfunc)
opt_prob.addVar('x1', 'c', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0, value=-3.0)
opt_prob.addVar('x2', 'c', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0, value=-4.0)
opt_prob.addObj('f')
print opt_prob
# Instantiate Optimizer (SDPEN) & Solve Problem WORKS
sdpen = SDPEN()
sdpen.setOption('iprint', -1)
sdpen(opt_prob)
print opt_prob.solution(0)
```

Then in spyder it works and prints the solution. BUT, from the prompt the command python ex1.py gives the usual error

```
ImportError: SDPEN shared library failed to import
```

and, yes, mingw32\bin is in the path. I even copied the mingw dlls to python Library\bin: same result. I'd really very glad to know how spyder manages to run without errors.